# Set default on mock for all methods to throw exception

Tags: c#, mocking, moq

I have C# handler (mediatr) that has code that is similar to for different _OSM methods:

```
await _OSM.Get()
```

I want to set default so that all the mock methods will throw exception.

I've tried

```
_OSM.SetReturnsDefault(new Exception(MyException))
_OSM.SetReturnsDefault(Task.FromResult(new Exception(MyException)))
```

What I get back for both cases are "false" instead of throwing the exception.

How do I throw exception for all methods called?

Comment: What do you mean by "Mog"? Probably not what the tag "mog" is about, or (you can see the explanation as tooltip when hovering over the tag)

Comment: @KlausGütter Wrong spelling, it's moq not mog.  https://github.com/moq/moq4/tree/a760c9888

Comment: Create the mock with Strict mock behavior. that way any members invoked that does not have a backing setup will throw an exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the mock with *"Strict"* mock behavior.

```
Mock<IMyInterface> _OSM = new Mock<IMyInterface>(MockBehavior.Strict);
```

That way any members invoked that do not have a backing setup will throw an exception.

Reference:

> Make mock behave like a "true Mock", raising exceptions for anything that doesn't have a corresponding expectation: in Moq slang a "Strict" mock; default behavior is "Loose" mock, which never throws and returns default values or empty arrays, enumerables, etc. if no expectation is set for a member

[Source](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#customizing-mock-behavior)

Comment: Is it possible to set it within the test case instead of at the creation at the instance ?  Is there a way to set it ?  You see my first case, is SetReturnsDefault to true, 2nd is SetReturnsDefault to false, 3rd to exception.  So if I were to use MockBehaviour.Strict, then I have to set up 2 instance of the mock.

Comment: @EBDS You will need to setup one isolated instance per test case otherwise you end up with race conditions